# Spring actuator endpoint seems to be called twice

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, health-monitoring

This does not block me in any way, just curious. Today during debugging my application I run into a weird logs:

```
{"@timestamp":"2020-04-17T16:30:55.128+0000","@version":"1","message":"Mapped to Actuator web endpoint 'health'","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping","thread_name":"qtp250197932-43","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000,"caller_class_name":"org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping","caller_method_name":"getHandler","caller_file_name":"AbstractHandlerMapping.java","caller_line_number":414}
{"@timestamp":"2020-04-17T16:30:55.128+0000","@version":"1","message":"Mapped to Actuator web endpoint 'health'","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping","thread_name":"qtp250197932-45","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000,"caller_class_name":"org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping","caller_method_name":"getHandler","caller_file_name":"AbstractHandlerMapping.java","caller_line_number":414}
```

Does anyone have an idea why I got two identical records about accessing health endpoint but from different threads?

Comment: Is this consistent, or a single occurrence? The endpoint might actually be called twice at the same time, which would explain the different threads since they are from a queued thread pool.

Comment: It's a good point, @PieterjanDeconinck! Indeed it was a one time occurence. Since my health check app pings it only once in 10 sec I've thought it's an issue. Probably someone queried the endpoint manually.